# Changing colour by name in a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display a scatterplot of the Yield per batch of a product:
(make-up of that dataset)

| Batch | Yield |
| --- | --- |
| PROD_191105001 | 88 |
| PROD_191106002 | 87 |
| PROD_191107003 | 86 |
| PROD_200203001 | 98 |
| PROD_200204002 | 99 |
| PROD_200205003 | 96 |

Now, I have a nice scatterplot for that, with average and quality chart rules (95th percentile 99th percentile) displayed.
I want to compare last years Batches to this years batches. The dots of last years batches should be greyed-out:
[image: Scatterplot Yield]

my spaghetti for that image:

```
ggplot(data=data) +
+ geom_point(aes(x=Batch, y=`normalized yield`))+
+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 115), colour = "green", size=1)+ %%set limit
+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 140), colour = "green", size=1)+ %%set limit
+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=(mean(`normalized yield`)-2*sd(`normalized yield`))), colour = "blue", size=1)+
+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=(mean(`normalized yield`)+2*sd(`normalized yield`))), colour = "blue", size=1)+
+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=(mean(`normalized yield`)-3*sd(`normalized yield`))), colour = "red", size=1)+
+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=mean(`normalized yield`)), linetype = "dashed")+
+ theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+
+ labs(title="Product Yield ", y="normalized yield in g", x= "Batch")
```

How do I tell R to split this dataset at a specific point, so I can change the colour makeup of that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The super quick version: use the `color` aesthetic option with a boolean 'less than' applied to `Batch` (note the addition of `colour` to `geom_point()`:

```
ggplot(data=data) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Batch, y=`normalized yield`, colour = Batch < 'PROD_20200101'))
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  labs(title="Product Yield ", y="normalized yield in g", x= "Batch")
```

A more flexible route would be to extract the date from the `Batch` column into its own column so that you can reference it directly (e.g. for coloring a plot)

```
library(ggplot2)  # For plotting
library(tibble)  # To make the sample data
library(tidyverse)  # For piping and data transformation
library(lubridate)  # To handle dates

# Sample Data -- I aligned the sample data to 2001 / 2002
data <- tribble(
  ~batch, ~yield,
  'PROD_20011001', 88,
  'PROD_20011102', 87,
  'PROD_20011203', 86,
  'PROD_20020101', 98,
  'PROD_20020202', 99,
  'PROD_20020303', 96,
)

# Create new columns
# Extract date_string, then date, then year
# You could do this all in one step if you want,
# I used three steps to help illustrate what is happening.
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    batch_date_str = substring(batch, 6),  # Extract the characters that represent the date from each batch
    batch_date = lubridate::ymd(batch_date_str),  # Convert those characters into a 'date'
    batch_year = lubridate::year(batch_date)  # Extract just the year from each batch date
  )

# If you want to color each year distinctly, convert `batch_year` to a factor
# so that ggplot does not use a continuous scale.
ggplot(data, aes(x=batch_date, y=yield, color=as_factor(batch_year))) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked, with a little bit of modification:

`ggplot(data=data) +
geom_point(aes(x=Batch, y=`normalized yield`, colour= grey(data$Batch < 'PROD_200203001'))+
theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+
 labs(title="Product Yield", y="normalized yield in g", x= "Batch")`

Yours gave me an additonal Legend to the right of the graph as well as no control over the colourscheme (or I'm just too new at this to figure out how to control the colourscheme.)

Comment: I also solemnly swear to do this tidy, with reading out the date when I have to do this project again next year!

Comment: Glad you found a modification that worked!
To remove an unwanted legend, you can use `theme(legend.position='none')`.
To handle discrete colors specifically, look into `scale_color_manual()`.  Best of luck with the project!